# iOS - Image Subview hinderng Tab Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Hey guys I am new to iOS & Objective C
I have a Tab Bar controller in which Im setting a custom background in `viewdidload` using the following code

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgname];
UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
if(backgroundImageView != nil)
    [backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];

backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
backgroundImageView.frame = getview.bounds;
backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[getview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
[getview addSubview:backgroundImageView];
[getview sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];
```

It was working fine but recently im facing an issue,
When I go to any other view controller (by push) and come back to the landing page the background image view is coming half way over the tab bar.
Also its happening randomly and not every time. I happen to notice that its often whenever i have a AlertView shown in other view controllers.

I tried subtracting the height of the tab bar from the frame rect of the background view and it  clipped the image just above tabbar but it still made the tab bar inaccessible.

attached a screen shot below!
Here you can see how its covering the UITabbar making it in accessible.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fChM6.png)

Thank you so much guys for taking a look into my question.

Comment: Can you add the screen shots of issue

Comment: @souvickcse Hi getview is self.view that I pass to a function I wrote for reusing this piece of code called from viewDidLoad.

Comment: @RameshMuthe hi i have attached the screenshot please have a look at it.